# deletion order for remove(rm) command

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

Redhat Linux 5.8 NFS mounting to NetApp storage.

I know rm -rf is very dangerous but I am investigating an issue where a user triggered and it was stopped while it's still in progress. Now I am assessing damages and would like to know how it traverses a directory. I tried look at the source code of rm but can't conclude how it determines the deletion order.

I've been searching around the communities and saw a few posts on this but it seems no one knows the answer.

Thanks,

Comment: Instead of guesstimating how far it got why not compare it to a backup?

Comment: I can restore from backups. Nonetheless, it's nice to know how rm works internally.

Answer (score 1):

A practical approach would be to create some test cases and just have a look.

If you look at the [actual code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/remove.c) it probably depends on the order items are read by `xfts_open`/[`fts_read`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fts_read).

The function that actually does the traversal and removal seems to be `rm_fts`. That function actually has a comment that states:

> This function is called once for every file system object that fts
>      encounters.  fts performs a depth-first traversal.

In addition a distribution might any number of changes to any of those components. So you might have to check a distribution individually on what they actually use/do.